# How to solve a set of PDEs derived from elasticity?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

The problem is discribed firstly, and a possoble strategy which might work (yet don't know how exactly) is suggested.

**How to gain an analytical solution?
Suggestion on numerical method is equally welcomed.**

Thank you SO much ~

**1. Problem Discription**

This is a nonhomogenous BVP. The domain is rectangular on xoz plane with vertexes of $(0,-h/2)$ and $(L,h/2)$. The dependent functions are components of displacement $u(x,z),w(x,z)$.

Two coupled PDEs are derived from 2D stress problem of transversely isotropic materials, i.e.
$$
(c_{11}\partial_{xx}+c_{44}\partial_{zz})u+(c_{13}+c_{44})\partial_{xz}w=0 \tag{1}
$$
$$
(c_{33}\partial_{zz}+c_{44}\partial_{xx})w+(c_{13}+c_{44})\partial_{xz}u=0 \tag{2}
$$
where, the only known relationship among the coefficients is $c_{13}=c_{11}\nu_t=c_{33}\nu_p$.

To prescribe the bcs, let's give the derivation of the components of stress, i.e.,
$$
\sigma_x=c_{11}\partial_xu+c_{13}\partial_zw
$$
$$
\sigma_z=c_{33}\partial_zw+c_{13}\partial_xu
$$
$$
\tau_{zx}=c_{44}(\partial_xw+\partial_zu)
$$
Then, the bcs are given as
$$
u(0,z)=u(L,z)=w(0,z)=w(L,z)=0
$$
$$
\sigma_z(x,-h/2)=-q
$$
$$
\tau_{zx}(x,-h/2)=\sigma_z(x,h/2)=\tau_{zx}(x,h/2)=0
$$

**2. Possible Strategy**

Following the strategy for isotropic materials with more constraints among the coefficients, another function $\Phi(x,z)$ is introduced to represent $u$ and $w$ as follows,
$$
u=\partial_{xz}\Phi
$$
$$
w=-\frac{c_{11}}{c_{13}+c_{44}}\partial_{xx}\Phi-\frac{c_{44}}{c_{13}+c_{44}}\partial_{zz}\Phi
$$

Then, eq.(1) is automatically satified, and eq.(2) becomes
$$
c_{11}c_{44}\partial_{xxxx}\Phi+(c_{11}c_{33}-c_{13}(c_{13}+2c_{44}))\partial_{xxzz}\Phi+c_{44}c_{33}\partial_{zzzz}\Phi=0
$$

It would be a Biharmonic equation for isotropic materials, which is not true for this case considered transversely isotropic materials.

Comment: Have you tried polynomial solutions? Timoshenko and Goodier, Theory of Elasticity, has similar problems for isotropic materials solved by degree 4 or smaller polynomials.